# Problem to using Telegram tdlib in Blazor client applications

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, telegram-api, tdlib

Someone knows how to use the telegram api library tdlib in the application Blazor WebAssembly from Microsoft. When I try to use in in web assembly throws exception, that bindings is not available for this project type.

Packages are:

```
<PackageReference Include="TDLib" Version="1.8.12" />
<PackageReference Include="tdlib.native" Version="1.8.12" />
```